# MahApps Icon Packs

Tags: c#, xaml, mahapps.metro

do I really need all IconPack DLLs if I want to distribute an app?
I only use 3 libraries, but when I remove the rest of the IconPack libraries, XAML throws errors.
Can anyone give me a tip?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Correct, you don't need them - just make sure none of your ResourceDictionaries or Styles use them.

Comment: Thanks for your information, now it works well without some libraries. the mistake was, i've deleted the entypo package

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the complete IconPacks package if you only want to use 3 of them. If size is a concern then you can install only the icons that you need.

As an example if you only want Entypo, FontAwesome and Material then install only these NuGet packages:

```
MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.Entypo
MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.FontAwesome
MahApps.Metro.IconPacks.Material
```